# Passing a $_GET value via a Switch statement to a method in a class

Tags: php, html, class, methods

> Original Post:
>
> I have a Paginate class setup, and it's working
>   beautifully.  However:
>
> I am only using 1 index file to display pretty much everything on my
>   website, using a whole bunch of included files. Therefore I am using
>   $_GET params to tell the script to load, f.ex: Memberlist.
>
> My article page uses ?view=News, ?view=Events, ?view=Videos, etc etc,
>   to display it's content.
>
> My pagination class however; posts solely it's own $_GET params for it
>   to work.
>
> So here's the problem; when you press Next, Previous, 1, 2, 3,
>   infinity, etc - the page reloads, naturally - and this removes
>   ?view=News and replaces it with the Paginator $_GET's instead.
>   Which... Messes up the whole thing. Figuratively speaking.
>
> I am using an elaborated version of:
>
> ```
> $pageTitle = $_GET['view'];
>    switch ($pageTitle)
>     {
>        case 'news':
>          $derivedTitle = 'News';
>          break;
>        case 'events':
>          $derivedTitle = 'Events';
>          break;
>        case 'news':
>          $derivedTitle = 'News';
>          break;
>     }
> ```
>
> I pass the Derived title variable to my paginator class as such:
>
> ```
> $pagi->getView = $derivedTitle;
> ```
>
> Which in theory should pass whatever value $derivedTitle holds, over
>   to my class var. However;
>
> When I, in the paginate method try to echo or print or whatever, the
>   derived value. I get... Absolutely nothing.
>
> Am I passing the variable to my method correctly? Because;
>
> ```
> $pagi->max_post_per_page = 10;
> ```
>
> ...works just fine.

Comment: Is "getView" is method or a member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved.
I was stupid enough to execute my method BEFORE actually asigning my value to it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with the same object that you had when you assigned the variable?  If its a different one the value will be lost.

Seems to me like you should just use $_SESSIONs to handle this.